# jQuery replace content with child of next parent

Tags: jquery, parent, lightbox, children, replacewith

I want to create a lightbox with div content and couldn't find a better way than to do it myself now.
I'd like to replace the current content with the next. Here's my code:

```
<div class="gallery_pic">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_inner">
            <img src="img"/>
            <p>content text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon_right"></div>
        </div>
        <img src="img" />
   </div>

   <div class="gallery_pic">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content_inner">
                <img src="img2"/>
                <p>content text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon_right"></div>
        </div>
        <img src="img2" />
    </div>    
</div>

<script>
    $('.gallery_pic').click(function(){
        $('.content', this).show(); 
    });

    $('.icon_right').click(function(){
        $('.content').replaceWith( ??? );
     });

</script>
```

When the gallery pic is clicked the lightbox with its content opens and when the  icon_right is clicked, the next .content of the next parent should be shown instead of the current one. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** While `.icon_right` is part of `.gallery_pic` click you'll need `event.stopPropagation()`

**2nd:** you need to hide other content `$('.content').hide();`

```
<script>
    $('.gallery_pic').click(function(){
        $('.content').hide();         //<<<<<<<<
        $('.content', this).show(); 
    });

    $('.icon_right').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();      //<<<<<<<<
        $(this).closest('.gallery_pic').next('.gallery_pic').click()
     });

</script>
```

use `.next('.gallery_pic')` to get the next element .. for previous you can use `.prev('.gallery_pic')`

> **Note:** There're more ways to make the lightbox but it all
>   depending of what you're intending to do .. the above code will work with
>   your way .. but If you need another way you can use `data` attribute
>   for each `img` and use just one lightbox to show the images

you can also add

```
$('.content').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();      //<<<<<<<<
});
```